# Using Select to filter a dataset that was defined using Wizards in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, select, dataset

In VS 2010 I defined a datasource/dataset using the builtin wizards.

Then my form load method has the following code:

```
this.specialTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = "..top secret..";
this.dataDataSet.customerTable.Select("customer_name like 'atwood%' "); 
this.specialTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataDataSet.customerTable);
```

The problematic line is the 2nd one where I try to 'Select' against a table in the dataset.  Do I need to assign the selected values to a new datatable and then assign the new datatable to the tableAdapter?

UPDATE1:

The SELECT statement does not work correctly.  The missing piece is the BindSource!

```
this.specialTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = "..top secret..";
this.specialBindingSource.Filter = "customer_name like 'atwood%' ";
this.specialTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataDataSet.customerTable);
```

Comment: answer with the 'bindingsource' and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SELECT statement does not work correctly. The missing piece is the BindSource!

```
this.specialTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = "..top secret..";     
this.specialBindingSource.Filter = "customer_name like 'atwood%' ";     
this.specialTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataDataSet.customerTable);
```